# what the concept of vault mean in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is there a concept called "vault" in perforce? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) is one of Perforce's competitors.

Answer (score 0):

Perforce and Vault, both are Software configuration Management tools. Valut is pretty new in this segment comparing perforce which is more mature product with lots of features. but in terms of Pricing, Valut is cheaper than perforce.

For more info, Please visit following url....

http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/

http://www.perforce.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Vault** can be a synonym for **trunk** / **mainline** / **master**; the most stable base of the project upon which development progresses.